# min-width and max-width in position fixed

Tags: html, css, position

How to make `min-width` and `max-width` work in positioned elements?

## What works

- The gray header must fill out 100% of the window width at all times
- The green/yellow elements must resize depending on window width (`min-width` / `max-width`)
- The blue header is an extension of the green header, but **without the gray background**

## What doesn't work

- The green/blue/yellow elements must follow the same width at all times when you resize the window (the blue element does not)

How to make the blue element work as described (without the gray background)? I'm open if there is a better solution :)

The blue header is fixed to `min-width`

https://jsfiddle.net/wahdr9j7/4/

```css
:root {
  --header-height: 50px;
  --page-header-height: 50px;
  --sidebar-width: 100px;
  --content-width-min: 400px;
  --content-width-max: 500px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header,
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}


/* this gray header has to fill up the full width */

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  background: gray;
}

header,
main {
  padding-left: var(--sidebar-width);
}

#header {
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

#page_header {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--page-header-height);
  background: blue;
}

#sidebar {
  width: var(--sidebar-width);
  min-height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

#header,
#page_header_content,
#content {
  max-width: var(--content-width-max);
  min-width: var(--content-width-min);
}

#content {
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  padding-top: calc(var(--header-height) + var(--page-header-height));
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header">
    main header
    <div style="text-align:right">right-aligned</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page_header">
    <div id="page_header_content">
      page header
      <div style="text-align:right">right-aligned</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="sidebar">
  sidebar
</div>
<main>
  <div id="content">
    content
    <div style="text-align:right">right-aligned</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Would it not make more sense here, if you applied the min- and max-width to the `header` element in the first place? (I mean the `header` element, not the div with that id.)

Comment: @CBroe the gray header in the background has to fill 100% of the window width at all time

Comment: Then introduce one _more_ wrapper element inside of that, that "groups" the green/blue/yellow ones?

Answer (score 1):

The `absolute` positioned div should be nested in the `min-width` div which should be set to `position: relative;`.

Add your custom `--content-width` `max` and `min`  on `#page_header` instead of `#page_header_content` so it's on the parent like the others.

Set `#page_header` to `relative` and `#page_header_content` to `absolute`.

```css
:root {
  --header-height: 50px;
  --page-header-height: 50px;
  --sidebar-width: 100px;
  --content-width-min: 400px;
  --content-width-max: 500px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

header,
#sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}


/* this gray header has to fill up the full width */

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: var(--header-height);
  background: gray;
}

header,
main {
  padding-left: var(--sidebar-width);
}

#header {
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

#page_header {
  position: relative;
  height: var(--page-header-height);
  background: blue;
}

#page_header_content {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

#sidebar {
  width: var(--sidebar-width);
  min-height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

#header,
#page_header,
#content {
  max-width: var(--content-width-max);
  min-width: var(--content-width-min);
}

#content {
  background: yellow;
}

main {
  padding-top: calc(var(--header-height) + var(--page-header-height));
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="header">
    main header
    <div style="text-align:right">right-aligned</div>
  </div>
  <div id="page_header">
    <div id="page_header_content">
      page header
      <div style="text-align:right">right-aligned</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
<div id="sidebar">
  sidebar
</div>
<main>
  <div id="content">
    content
    <div style="text-align:right">right-aligned</div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Fiddle for your convenience: [A fiddle for clarkk](https://jsfiddle.net/kameronmayers/pm527bn3/1/)

Comment: @clarkk is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

##### add these styles

```css
#header,
#page_header_content,
#content {
  max-width: var(--content-width-max);
  /* you can remove min-width: var(--content-width-min); for better responsive */
}
#page_header {
  position: absolute;
  height: var(--page-header-height);
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: var(--sidebar-width);
  /* remove background: blue */
}
#page_header_content {
  background: blue;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Then the blue element is not following the width when resizing the window

Comment: @clarkk fixed please check again

Comment: Can you create a new fiddle? I need the `min-width` because I don't want to fit phone screens